# jQuery addClass to second Table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I must be loosing it but I cannot addClass to the second table (with id 'table2') similar to the code below.  In my current code the tables are NOT labeled with ids, I just did it to show you which table I need to add a class to.

```
<div id="content_area">
  <table id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td>data</td>
      <td>
        <table><tr><td>data</td></tr></table>
        <table><tr><td>data</td></tr></table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table><tr><td>data</td></tr></table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="table2"><tr><td>data</td></tr></table>
</div>

$('#content_area').find('table:eq(1)').addClass('stuff');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
$('#content_area').children('table:eq(1)').addClass('stuff');
```

This requires the fewest changes to your existing code.

Comment: This is correct, i double checked my code and the table I was trying to grab was actually inside a FORM, but this essentially did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#content_area table').eq(4).addClass('stuff');
```

In your example, the table with `id="table2"` is actually the 5th table inside of content_area.  Start counting every `<table>` tag.

In case of dynamic # of tables within table 1 you should probably use:

```
$('#content_area').children('table:eq(1)').addClass('stuff');
```

This will look at the direct children of content_area and get the 2nd table from those children.  [Per [Kevin Buchan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781436/jquery-addclass-to-second-table/5781487#5781487)'s answer]

See:  http://jsfiddle.net/tAZht/2/

Comment: unfortunately my original code is dynamic and I cannot count on static tables so the number may change with exactly how many tables will be produced inside the first table ('table1').

Comment: updated my answer, @Kevin Buchan's answer might help you in the case of dynamic # of tables

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$('#content_area > table:nth-child(2)').addClass('stuff');
```

Comment: this will add class to every 2nd child that is two tables will get the class stuff. http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/aLmc2/4/

Comment: Perfect now and much optimized than iterating through each children and finding the correct index